# Kaminari and Sunspot undefined method page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to return all records that match a search in Kaminari and paginate the results. However, I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method 'page'
```

my controller code:

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Building) do
fulltext params[:search]
end
@buildings = @search.results.page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

I think I am just not understanding how to use Kaminari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page is a method you can call in relation, you can do this:

```
@buildings = Building.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id)).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

Comment: but the .per method does not exist on sunspot searches :|